# Azure API Egress Cost - Understanding cost of pulling data from Azure via API

Tags: azure

Does anyone know if there is a cost associated to the Azure API egress calls. We are calling the Azure API from external sources outside azure to extract data from the Azure resources. Wanted to know if there would be a cost of pulling the data from Azure via API. 
We are not using Azure API management, this is a custom solution which is pulling data from Azure.

Thanks very much for the help.
Cheers

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're referring to when you say "Azure API" (REST API? Custom API stack you built? Something else?) but... All egress pricing is documented under Bandwidth. Doesn't really matter how you pull data out of Azure's regions.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am referring to the REST API calls to Azure. Is there a cost around it?  Egress pricing is generally around network which is documented.

Comment: Depends on service. Azure Storage, for example, has documented cost per 10k operations (e.g. REST API calls). Cosmos DB has an RU-based pricing model. You'll need to read up on each service. Unfortunately, pricing-specific questions are off-topic here. You should be able to find all this info in the various Azure pricing docs.